# Combine three tables with JOIN

Tags: abap, opensql

I am facing the problem where I have three tables:
First table has data like:

```
A B C D  
1 2 3 4  
1 2 3 5
```

Second table has data like:

```
D E  
4 x  
6 y
```

Third table has data like:

```
E F  
x result1
y result2
```

What i need is a Query that displays all Values from the first table (obviously a left outer join) and if available the combination of the second and third table.

So the result would look somewhat like this:

```
A B C D E F  
1 2 3 4 x result 1  
1 2 3 5
```

However I cannot get a solution on this.

I already tried left joining two times (results in an error as it is not allowed in opensql) and inner joining the second and third table and trying to right join the first table (also not allowed in opensql).

How do I realize my desired result-table?

Comment: Can you post your code?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM first
  LEFT OUTER JOIN second
    ON second~d = first~d
  LEFT OUTER JOIN third
    ON third~e = second~e
  INTO TABLE @DATA(lt_result).
```

Sure you can do multiple `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s in OpenSQL.

The second join might also be an `INNER JOIN`, depending on what precisely you want.

Verified on a SAP NetWeaver 7.52 on SAP HANA 2.0.

Comment: Actually this does not work. This will result in an Error.

Comment: As said, I successfully executed this in an ABAP system. This is also not the first time I write multi-joins like this in OpenSQL. What NetWeaver version are you using?

Comment: I am Using 7.31. I have found a workaround already. Thanks anyways